# How to post photo and tag friend - using facebook sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, post, sdk, photo

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/).

Problem:

're post photo, but is not "tag"

```
public JsonResult PostFacebookTagPhoto()
{
    var path = Request["url"];
    var tag = Request["tags"];

    var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(Session["facebook.accessToken"].ToString());
    var file = new FileInfo(path);

    var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);

    var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

    try
    {
        var itens = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<List<TagFacebook>>(tag);
        dynamic me = Session["facebook.me"];
        var tags = new[] 
        { 
            new { itens[1].tag_uid, x = 30, y = 40},
            new { itens[2].tag_uid, x = 40, y = 50},
            new { itens[3].tag_uid, x = 30, y = 40},
            new { itens[4].tag_uid, x = 40, y = 50},
            new { tag_uid = (string)me.id, x = 50, y = 40}
        };

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = GetFacebookMessage();
        parameters.tags = tags;
        parameters.file = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
              ContentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(file.Extension.ToLowerInvariant()),
              FileName = file.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
        }.SetValue(data);
        try
        {
            facebookClient.Post("/me/photos", parameters); //LINE 133
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = "error", message = ex.Message, source = ex.Source, stacktrace = ex.StackTrace }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

        //SalvaDados(me, itens);

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
    catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = "error", message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSGAE:

> (Exception - #1399017) Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again.

Stack Trace:

> at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
>   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
>   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
>   at (...)\Controllers\SiteController.cs:line 133